# Weird mobile nav animation bug

Tags: javascript, css, animation, navigation

[CodePen of the nav](https://codepen.io/bbenefield/pen/GxMrXO?editors=0010)

On the first interaction with the mobile nav, it will open and close as expected but anything after that and there's a bug. It will begin to open and close instantly or the links will appear is weird orders.

What I need is for the mobile nav to first open from right to left, have each of the links to cascade into the view, starting from About all the way to Blog, and then I would like it to reverse when leaving the view.

Right now I don't have the logic implemented for the reverse but I need to work out this bug before I get to that.

### SNIPPET

```js
const bars = document.querySelector('.fa-bars');

bars.addEventListener('click', () => {
  const navItemsContainer = document.querySelector('.navbar__links-container');
  const navItems = document.querySelectorAll('.navbar__links-container__item');
  
  const sleep = ms => {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        return resolve();
      }, ms);
    });
  };
  
  const startNavAnimation = async () => {
    let count = 0;
    
    for (let item of navItems) {
      if (item.classList.contains('navbar__links-container__item--show')) {
        setTimeout(() => {
          item.style.transitionDelay = `${ count }s`
          item.classList.remove('navbar__links-container__item--show');
          count += .15;
        }, count);
      }
      else {
        item.style.transitionDelay = `${ count }s`
        item.classList.add('navbar__links-container__item--show');
        count += .15;
      }
    }
  };
  
  if (navItemsContainer.classList.contains('navbar__links-container--open')) {
    navItems[ navItems.length - 1 ].addEventListener('transitionend', () => {
      navItemsContainer.classList.remove('navbar__links-container--open');
    });
  }
  else {
    navItemsContainer.classList.add('navbar__links-container--open');
  }
  
  startNavAnimation();
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.navbar {
  background: #f2f2f2;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.navbar__mobile-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  width: 100%;
}

.fa-bars {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.navbar__links-container {
  background: inherit;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: flex-end;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  left: 100%;
  transition: left .25s, width .25s;
  width: 0%;
}

.navbar__links-container__item {
  left: 52px;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  position: relative;
  transition: left .25s;
  width: auto;
}

.navbar__links-container--open {
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.navbar__links-container__item--show {
  left: -63px;
}
```

```html
    <nav class="navbar">
      <div class="navbar__mobile-container">
        <div class="navbar__logo-container">
          <a class="navbar__logo-container__logo">BB</a>
        </div>
        
        <div class="navbar__hamburger-container">
          <i class="fas fa-bars">MENU</i>
        </div>
      </div>

      <ul class="navbar__links-container">
        <li class="navbar__links-container__item">
          <a class="navbar__links-container__item__link">About</a>
        </li>
        <li class="navbar__links-container__item">
          <a class="navbar__links-container__item__link">Portfolio</a>
        </li>
        <li class="navbar__links-container__item">
          <a class="navbar__links-container__item__link">Blog</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
</nav>
```

### NOTES

- I think the problem is the first `if` statement in the `bars` event-handler. Something about the way it's waiting for the `transitionend` event but the `startNavAnimation` hasn't been called.

Comment: Is all of the animation supposed to be inside the `click` `eventListener`?

Comment: I dont know of a better way but yea. I want all that to happen when the menu is clicked on. I guess i could seperate it a bit, like the transitionend event.

Comment: It might be capturing the click events together

Comment: So that it gets one click (the first time), a second click (to close it), and then the third click gets the first again, so it opens and closes, etc.

Comment: Weird, is this common? What would you suggest i do to fix/prevent this in the future?

Comment: I don't really know, just you might want to pull the animation outside the click event (as a separate function) and then call it inside the click event. I think it's being created every time a click is captured.

Comment: Well it was worth a shot but no dice. Moved the function `sleep` and `startNavAnimation` to the top, moved necessary variables as well, and it's just doing the same.

Comment: Hmm. I'll see what I can do

Comment: Appreciate it, here's a pen if it makes it easier [CODEPEN](https://codepen.io/bbenefield/pen/GxMrXO?editors=0010)

Comment: I'll be around for a while tonight, comment back if the solution doesn't work or presents other issues - a nice side effect is that the close animation is working!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two issues.

- One is that you are adding a new event listener inside of the click event listener. I moved that outside.
- The second issue is that the --open class is going to be there while the menu is opening or closing so you need another way to test open or closed status. To make the Codepen clear to understand, I just used an `isOpen` flag.

https://codepen.io/Jason_B/pen/jzGwQX?editors=0010

I like using classes for this, and your code shows that you do too, so you might want to have a class for open status and a class for visibility.

Comment: Is there a reason you used `var` for `isOpen`?

Comment: Can't change the value of a `const`, I like `let` inside of a function and `var` in a bigger block level scope. `var` helps me make it clear to myself  that something is going to be accessed and modified in other functions. I usually `"use strict"` js so not declaring it isn't an option.